# My laptop charger is turning off during any gpu usage and then the battery drains 5% in one minute

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, charger

Yesterday I updated my drivers with Geforce Experience. I didn't think anything of it. But today I opened Blender and when I switch to a rendered view or simply render any project, my laptop charger just turns off. My battery also looses 5% in 1 minute after this happens. I've never experienced this before and I've searched the internet for any kind of solution or a similar problem. It doesn't happen in any other program either. Just this one. But I went to a support team for this program and they had never heard of this.

MSI
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-770HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
16.0 GB RAM
Intel(R) Graphics 630
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070

Comment: I forgot to mention that when rendering a project, it uses my gpu

Comment: Restart, make sure "Blender" is not running, check the AC adapter and the battery charging level. Wait one-half hour, start "Blender" and use normally. What happens?

Comment: Did this twice earlier. Same occurrence.

Comment: The charger may be under-powered.  Start up, do not start applications, let battery charge to 100% (Battery gauge) .  Then test again and watch battery discharge.

Comment: What do you mean by "charger just turns off"?

Comment: the chargers light indicator to show it's plugged in and charging turns off and the laptop stops charging

Comment: Is it the original charger?

Comment: yes it's the original charger

Comment: I experienced something similar but not identical and found my battery had gone bad. Is that a possibility in your case?

Answer (score 3):

When rendering (or gaming or any other power-hungry application), your system uses more power than your charger can deliver by itself.

The extra power your system needs comes from the battery, which will then off course discharge, as the charger is already delivering all its power to your system. The charger does not turn off, although it may look like it.

My MSI laptop exhibits the same behaviour (although not in a very dramatic fashion) so I'm surprised the support team never heard of this. A larger (high quality) power supply will probably help, as will setting your system to a low(er) power profile.